# .htaccess RuleRewrite issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a site with a page that is hidden from the main navigation. Recently, I have run across some odd URLs linking to the page in Google results. I wanted to use my htaccess file to fix them, but have been unsuccessful so far.

My hidden page is: www.mediware.com/share-the-science

but I have run across this URL: www.mediware.com/share-the-science/12-home-care?start=28

in my Google results.

I want to rewrite
www.mediware.com/share-the-science/12-home-care?start=28

to

www.mediware.com/share-the-science

I have tried the following solutions, but none have worked:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/share-the-science/12-home-care.*$ http://www.mediware.com/share-the-science
RedirectMatch 301 ^/share-the-science/12-home-care/.*$ http://www.mediware.com/share-the-science



RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^start=28$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^share-the-science$ /share-the-science/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]


Redirect 301 http://www.mediware.com/share-the-science/12-home-care?start=28 http://www.mediware.com/share-the-science
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^start=28$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^share-the-science /share-the-science/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Without final `$`, because it's not the end.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either. It still goes to www.mediware.com/share-the-science/12-home-care?start=28

Comment: Not with this rewrite. Clear your cache and test with other browser.